# Coordinate System Mapping Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems

When given a coordinate system A:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}

a coordinate system rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise written in terms of A as $^A_BR$:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}

and a point $^BP$ written in terms of B:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1
  \end{bmatrix}

We can get $^AP$ by through the following equation:

$^AP = (^A_BR) (^BP)$

such that $^AP$ is:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}

I've never found a formal proof that states why this is true for any point. It's slightly confusing to me why this works, and I feel like a formal proof might help me understand it better. I'm currently reading through [Introduction to Robotics: Mechanics and Control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543613), but they never gave an adequate description why this works. Any help?